# Unable to change environment variable

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, asp.net-core-2.1

I am having trouble changing the publish variable within `web.config` because it amounts to nothing.

Once I set the variable in `web.config` to `Development`, for example, when I launch the application, it still says that the environment variable is `Production`.

[image]

As you can see below, the `web.config` states that I have set the variable to `Development`.

[image]

I am out of ideas and genuinely unsure whether variables can be set this way anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your first screenshot, it looks like you are running your application from the command line, probably using `dotnet run`. In this case, you should note that the `web.config` is completely ignored.

The `web.config` is only to configure IIS for when you actually deploy your application on IIS. If you run it in any other way, the `web.config` is not being used and you will have to configure the environment in a different way.

If you want to run the application from the command line, you can set the environment variable using `set`:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
dotnet run
```

If you use a standard ASP.NET Core template, there should also be a `launchSettings.json` file which configures the default launch settings. If you specify the environment there, `dotnet run` will automatically pick it up when you run the application from the application’s root directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I do have another question, though. If I were to deploy the app on a service such as Plesk rather than IIS, for example, is it possible to change the environment variable from `Production` to something else there instead?

Comment: That mostly depends on the operating system and hosting process. But yeah, as long as you set the environment variable as the process starts, that works just fine. In Linux, this would typically look like this: `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development dotnet YourApp.dll` – If you put it like that in your startup script, then that will work fine.

Comment: If you use something like system.d to launch the application, you can also specify process environment variables in the service definition. See for example [this chapter in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-the-service-file).